# Read MIDI Device Input In Ruby

Tags: ruby, midi

Is is possible to trap the MIDI signals being sent by my keyboard connected via MIDI-USB in Ruby? If not Ruby, how would I do it in C so I can make a Ruby extension?

Comment: What platform (OS) are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Use PortMidi, which is part of the [PortMedia](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/) project. A little Googling showed several references to existing Ruby bindings to PortMidi, so you may not need to do much/any work to get things running.

#### What is PortMedia?

- PortMedia is a set of APIs and
  library implementations for music and
  other media.
- PortMedia is open-source
  and runs on Windows, Macintosh, and
  Linux.
- Currently, libraries support
  Audio I/O and MIDI I/O.